# Grouping ng-repeat elements together

Tags: angularjs

I am wondering if there is a built-in Angular way of binding 2 rows of a table to a single JSON object just like you would normally with a single row. For example, I can bind a JS Array to the DOM like this:

```
       <tbody id="tbActivities">
            <tr ng-repeat="activity in activities" ng-click="removeItem(activity)">
                <td>{{ activity.Description }}</td>
                <td>{{ activity.Count }}</td>
                <td>{{ activity.CustomerName }}</td>
                <td>{{ activity.Date }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

This will just create a `<tr>` for each `activity` that I have. However, I want to be able to have another `<tr>` right after each of the current rows that displays a larger Detail of the current item. So the DOM would then look something more like this

```
       <tbody id="tbActivities">
            <tr ng-repeat="activity in activities" ng-click="removeItem(activity)">
                <td>{{ activity.Description }}</td>
                <td>{{ activity.Count }}</td>
                <td>{{ activity.CustomerName }}</td>
                <td>{{ activity.Date }}</td>
            </tr>
                <tr class="ActivityDetail">
                   <td></td>
                   <td colspan="3">
                         {{ activity.Detail }}
                   </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Where the Detail property of the activity is actually HTML and is displayed only when the user clicks on the associated row.  What is the best way to make this happen? Would I instead wrap both `<tr>`'s in another tag and have that tag use the ng-repeat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use ng-repeat-start.

```
    <tbody id="tbActivities">
        <tr ng-repeat-start="activity in activities" ng-click="removeItem(activity)">
            <td>{{ activity.Description }}</td>
            <td>{{ activity.Count }}</td>
            <td>{{ activity.CustomerName }}</td>
            <td>{{ activity.Date }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-end class="ActivityDetail">
           <td></td>
           <td colspan="3">
                 {{ activity.Detail }}
           </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```